# How to work out a Yes or no

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to compile a simple program to bake a cake. The variables are basically

1. If cake burning = Yes then turn over off.
2. If temp < 120deg turn over up.
3. If temp > 190deg turn over down.

Also if the cake is burning and the answer is yes then the program should end there.

I'm all good for parts 2 and 3 using if-else but I've hit a bit of a roadblock with the yes/no option. I want the user to select the value of cake_burning variable via an JOptionPane.

Comment: So what have you tried? Post the code or a screenshot of what you have so far _for the part you need help with_.

Comment: i am not quite sure, but this could be a possible duplicate of [how do i compare string in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) since theyr topic seems to be the same.

Comment: Is "cake burning" a variable? What about making a boolean out of it?
Otherwise I'd go with @KevinEsche, you actually need to compare strings: `if("Yes".equals(cake_burning)
 {//do stuff}`

Answer (score 0):

`YES` or `NO` is still only a choice of `TRUE`/`FALSE` responses.

You will still use your `IF` `THEN` scenario, substituting (even if only in your head) `YES` where you test for `TRUE` and `NO` where you test for `FALSE`.

You COULD define variables or constants for `YES` and `NO` if you wanted, but there's no need:

```
if (CakeBurning) then {     // cake is burning, true (or yes)
    Oven.power=0;
}
```

In most languages `if (CakeBurning)` will return the same as `if (CakeBurning==TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to select if the cake is burning or not in a JOption pane, you can proceed like this.

```
int cake_burning = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
             null, 
             "Is the cake burning?",
             JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

if(cake_burning == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // turn the oven off
}
```